# If the underlying metric is complete, then so is its induced Hausdorff metric

Tags: solution-verification, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces, hausdorff-distance

Let $(E, d)$ be a metric space and $\mathcal C$ the set of all non-empty compact subsets of $E$. We define [a metric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4501594/hausdorff-distance-on-the-metric-space-containing-compact-subsets) $d_H$ on $\mathcal C$ by
$$
d_H (A, B) := \max \left  \{  \max_{x \in B} d(x, A),  \max_{y \in A} d (y, B) \right \}\quad \forall A,B \in \mathcal C,
$$
with $d(x, A) := \inf_{y \in A} d(x, y)$. I'm trying to prove below property which I have seen from this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance#Properties).

> **Theorem:** If $E$ is complete, then so is $\mathcal C$.

Could you please have a check on my attempt?

---

**My attempt:** Assume $(A_n) \subset \mathcal C$ is a Cauchy sequence. Let
$$
L := \{ \lim x_n \mid  (x_n) \in (A_n)\text{ convergent}\}.
$$

1. $L$ is compact.

Let $(x_n) \subset L$. For each $n$, there is  a sequence $(x_{n, m})_m \in (A_m)$ such that $x_{n, m} \xrightarrow{m \to \infty} x_n$. There is a subsequence $\varphi$ of $\mathbb N$ such that $d(x_{n, \varphi (n)}, x_n) < 1/n$.  Let $y_n := x_{n, \varphi (n)} \in A_{\varphi (n)}$.

> [Lemma 1:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4502825/let-a-n-be-a-cauchy-sequence-w-r-t-hausdorff-metric-and-x-n-in-a-n) Assume $(A_n) \subset \mathcal C$ is a Cauchy sequence and $(x_n) \in (A_n)$. Then $(x_n)$ has a Cauchy subsequence.

By our *Lemma 1*, there is a subsequence $\psi$ of $\mathbb N$ such that $(y_{\psi (n)})$ is Cauchy. Because $E$ is complete, $(y_{\psi (n)})$ is convergent. Hence $(x_{\psi (n)})$ is convergent.

2. $A_n \to L$.

Assume the contrary that $A_n \not \to L$. Then there is $\varepsilon >0$ and a subsequence $\varphi$ of $\mathbb N$ such that $d_H (A_{\varphi (n)}, L) > \varepsilon$ for all $n$. There are $2$ cases.

- There exists a subsequence $\psi$ of $\varphi$ and a sequence $(a_{\psi (n)}) \in (A_{\psi (n)})$ such that $d (a_{\psi (n)}, L) > \varepsilon$ for all $n$.

By *Lemma 1*, there is a subsequence $\lambda$ of $\psi$ such that $(a_{\psi (n)}) \in (A_{\psi (n)})$ is Cauchy.

> [Lemma 2:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4503436/extend-a-cauchy-subsequence-to-a-whole-cauchy-sequence) Assume $(A_n) \subset \mathcal C$ is a Cauchy sequence, $\varphi$ a subsequence of $\mathbb N$, and $(x_{\varphi (n)}) \in (A_{\varphi (n)})$ a Cauchy sequence. Then there is a Cauchy sequence $(y_n) \in (A_n)$ such that $x_{\varphi (n)} = y_{\varphi (n)}$ for all $n$.

By *Lemma 2*, there is a Cauchy sequence $(y_n) \in (A_n)$ such that $a_{\psi (n)} = y_{\psi (n)}$ for all $n$. It follows that $\lim y_n =: \ell \in L$. Then there is $N$ such that $d(y_n, L) \le d(y_n, \ell) < \varepsilon$ for all $n >N$. There is $n_0$ such that $\varphi (n_0) > N$. Hence $d(a_{\varphi (n_0)}, L) = d(y_{\varphi (n_0)}, L) < \varepsilon$. This is a contradiction.

- There exists a subsequence $\psi$ of $\varphi$ and a sequence $(\ell_{\psi (n)}) \subset L$ such that $d (\ell_{\psi (n)}, A_{\psi (n)}) > \varepsilon$ for all $n$.

Because $L$ is compact, there is a subsequence $\lambda$ of $\psi$ and $\ell \in L$ such that $\ell_{\lambda (n)} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} \ell$. Then
$$
d(\ell, A_{\psi (n)}) \ge d (\ell_{\psi (n)}, A_{\psi (n)})- d(\ell, \ell_{\psi (n)}) > \varepsilon/2
$$
for $n$ large enough. Because $\ell \in L$, there is a sequence $(y_n) \in (A_n)$ such that $y_n \to \ell$. This implies $d(\ell, A_n) \to 0$, which is a contradiction. This completes the proof.

Comment: Maybe we want to prove that $C$ is compact

Comment: @FShrike My next post would be "If $E$ is totally bounded, then so is $\mathcal C$" :v

Comment: The empty set is compact and I think we can find Cauchy sequences convergent to it. How does $d_H(A,\emptyset)$ work?

Comment: @FShrike "... $\mathcal C$ the set of all *non-empty* compact subsets of $E$"

Comment: Oh whoops :) apologies

Comment: @FShrike You're very welcome. I'm very happy to see you again.

Comment: Thanks - I've just scrolled through your old questions, I'm afraid I don't recognise anything off the top of my head... where have we met before?

Comment: By $(x_n)\in (A_n)$ do you mean $x_n \in A_n$ for all $n$?

Comment: @ArcticChar exactlyy.

Comment: @FShrike you commented (and answered) some of my questions before...