# Is there a characterization of convergence in Hausdorff metric in terms of that in the underlying metric?

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, hausdorff-distance

Let $(E, d)$ be a metric space and $\mathcal C$ the set of all non-empty compact subsets of $E$. We endow $\mathcal C$ with [the Hausdorff metric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4501594/hausdorff-distance-on-the-metric-space-containing-compact-subsets) $d_H$. It's well-known [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4504189/if-the-underlying-metrics-are-equivalent-then-so-are-their-induced-hausdorff-me) the topology of $\mathcal C$ depends on that of $E$, not on $d$. One example to illustrate this independece is as follows. Let $A,A_n \in \mathcal C$ such that $A_n \to A$ in $d_H$. [Then](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4503460/if-the-underlying-metric-is-complete-then-so-is-its-induced-hausdorff-metric)
$$
\lim_n A_n = \{ \lim x_n \mid  (x_n) \in (A_n)\text{ convergent}\}.
$$

This means the limit point $A$ of the sequence $(A_n)$ is characterized only by the convergent sequences in $E$. My question is the following.

> Is there a simple characterization of $d_H(A_n, A) \to 0$ in terms of convergent sequences in $E$?

Comment: I think the final question should have a $\exists A$ somewhere. As it stands the displayed equation is an answer.