# Let $A_n \to A$ in $d_H$, $\mu_n \to \mu$ weakly, and $\operatorname{supp} \mu_n \subset A_n$. Then $\operatorname{supp} \mu \subset A$

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces, weak-convergence, borel-measures, hausdorff-distance

Let $(E, d)$ be a metric space and $\mathcal C$ the set of all non-empty compact subsets of $E$. We define the [Hausdorff metric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4501594/hausdorff-distance-on-the-metric-space-containing-compact-subsets) $d_H$ on $\mathcal C$ by
$$
d_H (A, B) := \max \left  \{  \max_{x \in B} d(x, A),  \max_{y \in A} d (y, B) \right \}\quad \forall A,B \in \mathcal C,
$$
with $d(x, A) := \inf_{y \in A} d(x, y)$. I'm trying to prove a property from page 37 of Santambrogio's *Optimal Transport for Applied Mathematicians: Calculus of Variations, PDEs, and Modeling*.

> **Theorem:** Let $A, A_n \in \mathcal C$ such that $A_n \to A$ in $d_H$. Let $\mu, \mu_n$ be non-negative finite Borel measures such that $\operatorname{supp} \mu_n \subset A_n$ and that $\mu_n \overset{\ast}{\rightharpoonup} \mu$. Then $\operatorname{supp} \mu \subset A$.

In below attempt, I can only prove the thereom in the case $\mu, \mu_n$ are probability measures.

> How can we prove this theorem in its full generality?

---

**My attempt:** First, we have the following [equivalent formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4501730/a-different-formulation-of-hausdorff-distance) of $d_H$, i.e.,
$$
d_H (A, B) = \inf \{ \varepsilon >0 \mid  A \subset  B_{\varepsilon}, B \subset A_{\varepsilon} \} \quad \forall A,B \in \mathcal C.
$$

Here $A_{\varepsilon} := \{x \in E \mid d(x, A) \le \varepsilon\}$ and $B_{\varepsilon} := \{x \in E \mid d(x, B) \le \varepsilon\}$ being the $\varepsilon$-neighborhoods of $A, B$ respectively.

Fix $\varepsilon > 0$. First, we'll prove that $A_{\varepsilon}$ is closed. Let $(x_n) \subset A_{\varepsilon}$ such that $x_n \to x \in E$. We have
$$
d(x, a) \le d(x, x_n) + d(x_n, a) \quad \forall a \in A, \forall n.
$$

Then for all $n$,
$$
\begin{align}
d(x, A) &= \inf_{a \in A} d(x,a) \\
&\le d(x, x_n) + \inf_{a \in A} d(x_n,a) \\
&= d(x, x_n) + d(x_n, A) \\
&\le d(x,x_n) + \varepsilon.
\end{align}
$$

Taking the limit $n \to \infty$, we get $d(x,A) \le \varepsilon$ and thus $x \in A_{\varepsilon}$.

Because $A_n \to A$ in $d_H$, there is $n_{\varepsilon }$ such that $A_n \subset A_{\varepsilon }$ for all $n \ge n_{\varepsilon }$. This implies
$$
\mu_n (A_{\varepsilon}) \ge \mu_n (A_n) = 1 \quad \forall n \ge n_{\varepsilon}.
$$

By [Portmanteau theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4434275/the-space-of-bounded-lipschitz-continuous-functions-is-dense-in-that-of-bounded?noredirect=1&lq=1), we have
$$
\mu (A_{\varepsilon }) \ge \limsup_n \mu_n (A_{\varepsilon }) \ge 1.
$$

Notice that $A$ is closed, so $A = \bigcap_{\varepsilon >0} A_{\varepsilon}$ and thus $A_{\varepsilon} \searrow A$ as $\varepsilon \searrow 0$. It follows that
$$
\mu (A) = \lim_{\varepsilon \searrow 0} \mu (A_{\varepsilon}) = 1.
$$

It follows that $\operatorname{supp} \mu \subset A$.

---

**Update:** I have found another proof as follows.

We define $f_n (x) := d(x, A_n)$ and $f (x) := d(x, A)$. Notice that
$$
f_n (x) \le d(x, y) + d (y, A_n) = d(x, y) + f_n (y) \quad \forall x,y \in E.
$$

By symmetry, we have $|f_n (x)-f_n (y)| \le d(x,y)$. Thus $f_n$ is $1$-Lipschitz. Moreover, $f_n$ is compactly supported. It follows that $f_n \in C_b (E)$, i.e., $f_n$ is continuous bounded. Similarly, $f \in C_b (E)$. We have the following [equivalent formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4501730/a-different-formulation-of-hausdorff-distance) of $d_H$, i.e.,
$$
d_H (A, B) = \max_{x \in E} |d(x, A) - d(x, B)|.
$$

It follows that $|f_n (x)-f(x)| = |d(x, A_n) - d(x, A)| \le d_H(A_n, A)$. It follows that $f_n \to f$ uniformly. By this [convergence result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4504013/let-mu-n-overset-ast-rightharpoonup-mu-and-f-n-to-f-in-cdot), we get
$$
0 = \int_E f_n \mathrm d \mu_n \to \int_E f \mathrm d \mu.
$$

Hence $\mu$ is supported on $A$. This completes the proof.

Comment: What is your definition of weak convergence for infinite measures?

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you so much! It should be non-negative finite measures. Corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mu_n \to \mu$ weakly and $\nu_n=\frac {\mu_n} {\mu_n(E)},\nu=\frac {\mu} {\mu(E)}$ then $\nu_n \to \nu$ weakly. Also, $supp(\nu_n)=supp (mu_n)$ and $supp (\nu)=supp (\mu)$.

Comment: Ah If $\mu_n \overset{\ast}{\rightharpoonup} \mu$ then $\mu_n (E) \to \mu (E)$.